# Elastic CSS Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this css menu with the bottom line will follow moves and back to origin when mouse out

However, the positioning a bit weird.
Anyone knows how to center the line to the middle?

```js
var activeOffset = $('nav ul .active').position().left;
var activeItemWidth = $('nav ul .active').width();

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.dot').css('left', activeOffset + activeItemWidth / 2);;
});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  $('.dot').css('left', activeOffset + activeItemWidth / 2);

});

$('nav ul li').hover(function() {
  var navOffset = $(this).position().left;
  var navItemWidth = $(this).width();

  $('.dot').css('left', navOffset + navItemWidth / 2);

});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  oveflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  /* -webkit-transform: translateX(-15%);
          transform: translateX(-15%);*/
  border-radius: 50px;
  /*  width: 130%;*/
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #da98b4;
}

nav ul li.active a {
  color: black;
}

nav .dot {
  background-color: #da98b4;
  width: 76px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CCCC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DDDD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EEEE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FFFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GGGG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HHHH</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This might be a silly answer so I have put it as a comment but for your fiddle I added "activeOffset = activeOffset - 35;" which lined it up for your example. Putting a fixed number in there does make me think this will not work all the time but works for your example.

Comment: @PaulD check my answer and you'll see where the trouble was.

Comment: Oh- very nice. Great answer! You live and learn :-)

Comment: By the way, @clement loving the animation :D

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, great use of a common technique but done very well. Although there is still some strange behavior not related to the question asked, but when hovering between the links.

Comment: @PaulD, yes I noticed it too. There seems to be some margin between the nav elements. It causes the "sliding line thingy" to reset back to the first element. Removing the mouseout eventlistener could solve it, but now that leaves the wrong tab showing as selected/active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var activeOffset = $('nav ul .active').position().left;
var activeItemWidth = $('nav ul .active').width();

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.dot').css({
   'left' : activeOffset,
   'width' : activeItemWidth
});
});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
 $('.dot').css({
   'left' : activeOffset,
   'width' : activeItemWidth
});

});

$('nav ul li').hover(function() {
  var navOffset = $(this).position().left;
  var navItemWidth = $(this).width();
$('.dot').css({
   'left' : navOffset,
   'width' : navItemWidth
});

});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  oveflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  /* -webkit-transform: translateX(-15%);
          transform: translateX(-15%);*/
  border-radius: 50px;
  /*  width: 130%;*/
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #da98b4;
}

nav ul li.active a {
  color: black;
}

nav .dot {
  background-color: #da98b4;
  width: 76px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">官方首页</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">老虎机</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">真人娱乐</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">捕鱼游戏</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">体育博彩</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">彩票游戏</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">火热优惠</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">特级贵宾</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Check this :)

Comment: love this. Fixed the jaggy movement sometimes.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @clement cheeers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run this snippet bellow to see the code working.

```js
var activeOffset = $('nav ul .active').position().left;
// var activeItemWidth = $('nav ul .active').width();

$('document').ready(function() {

  $('.dot').css('left', activeOffset);
});

$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  $('.dot').css('left', activeOffset)

});

$('nav ul li').hover(function() {
  var navOffset = $(this).position().left;
  //Also removed the nav width
  //var navItemWidth = $(this).width();

  $('.dot').css('left', navOffset /*+ navItemWidth / 2*/ );

});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  oveflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  /* -webkit-transform: translateX(-15%);
          transform: translateX(-15%);*/
  border-radius: 50px;
  /*  width: 130%;*/
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #da98b4;
}

nav ul li.active a {
  color: black;
}

nav .dot {
  background-color: #da98b4;
  width: 76px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CCCC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DDDD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EEEE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FFFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GGGG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HHHH</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```